# EmberJS - Nested Routes/Resources

Tags: ember.js, routes, ember-router

Suppose that I want my desired URLs for my application to be:

- `domain.com/A/:aID`
- `domain.com/A/:aID/B/:bID`
- `domain.com/A/:aID/B/:bID/C?param1:123`

And each state will be a completely different view/template.

Basic code that I currently have is:

```
this.resource('A', { path: 'A/:id' }, function () {
    this.resource('A.B', { path: 'B/:id' }, function () {
        this.route('A.B.C');
    }
}
```

Is this a proper way of accomplishing this? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

Your route declaration should be just `C`, not `A.B.C`. Resources don't keep their parent context but routes do. You can also use nested routes instead of nested resources if you want.

```
this.route('A', { path: 'A/:id' }, function () {
    this.route('B', { path: 'B/:id' }, function () {
        this.route('C');
    }
}
```

Other than that, I think your method will work just fine.

Comment: Thanks! One followup. Say that I am on B or C and I want to have a "back" button to take the user back to the previous state AND I don't want to use the window.history(-1), how would I go about this?

Comment: I imagine you want to do that so you can take the user back to a previous page without going back in the browser history? I think something like `window.history.replaceState(window.history.previous)` might work. (Found in the [history property documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.history).)

Comment: How could I do it with a {{link-to}} using the model from A on the B view?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure how you would do that. I imagine that you'd have to store the last visited route and model and put then in the `link-to` helper yourself.